# OTF Font on web server?

Tags: html, css

I wonder is it possbile to use otf fonts on web server? I am asking this question because the following font works well on localhost but does not when I upload it on IIS.

```
@font-face 
{
    font-family:"CustomArabicFont";
    src: url("fonts/NassimArabicTEST-Regular.otf");
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

This is how I am calling this font:

```
.custom-ar-font 
{
    font-family: CustomArabicFont, Tahoma;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to configure the proper MIME types. OTF fonts should have a MIME-type of [`application/font-sfnt`](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/font-sfnt).

Check these links for implementation details:

- http://sebduggan.com/blog/serving-web-fonts-from-iis/
- http://codingstill.com/2013/01/set-mime-types-for-web-fonts-in-iis/